# Here API Routing - Avoid unpaved roads

Tags: here-api

can anyone write how to avoid unpaved roads in Here routing (or truck routing) in REST API? I have checked API and I couldn't find answer. Routing API routes cars or trucks via dirty roads, what is unaccepted.

Comment: The only thing that I have found so far is ;dirtRoad:-3 in RouteFeatureType, but it still sometimes drives through dirt roads

Comment: That is the correct attribute to apply to avoid dirt roads (dirtRoad:-3). You mention that it is still driving thru dirt roads. Can you share an example of that Routing request?

Answer (score 1):

RouteFeatureType:The routing features can be used to define special conditions on the calculated route. The user can weight each feature with non-positive weights.
Possible paramers are: tollroad, motorway, boatFerry, railFerry, tunnel, dirtRoad,
park.

The Feature weights are used to define weighted conditions on special route features like tollroad,
motorways, etc.

-3 strictExclude The routing engine guarantees that the route does not contain strictly
excluded features. If the condition cannot be fulfilled no route is returned.

-2 softExclude The routing engine does not consider links containing the corresponding
feature. If no route can be found because of these limitations the condition is weakened.

-1 avoid The routing engine assigns penalties for links containing the corresponding
feature.

0 normal The routing engine does not alter the ranking of links containing the
corresponding feature.

Of course does the map content play also a huge role here. It is needed for the routing that the attribution e.g. for a dirt road (unpaved road segment) is set correctly. 
You can also check details and report issues here: https://mapcreator.here.com